# Can't add SQL Compact Edition to my VB.net Application

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I am new to using SQL Compact Edition with VB.net 2012.

I have come across the following site that should hopefully help me get started: http://sharecom-clemo.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/code-sample-demonstrating-how-to_07.html

However it says 'Go to the References page of the project properties and reference the SQL Server CE assembly first. Then you can import the SQL Server CE namespace.'

I hope I am correct in doing this by click on 'Project' > 'Add Reference'

Then choosing 'Microsoft SQL Server Compact Control'.

However when selecting that and clicking on 'OK' I get a error not allowing me to add it as it says that it can't register the ActiveX type library.

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, and is this what I should be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the Assemblies tab (not COM), and browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop and a a reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll